# DRAC 4/I Console Redirection Applet Perpetually Stuck Connecting

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, ipmi, drac

## The Problem

---

Attempting to connect via the Java virtual console results in perpetual attempt at connecting, even though the applet otherwise loads properly and attempts to connect to the proper address, it never connects.

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elvk7.png) [Applet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkMQm.png)

## What I've Tried

---

Firefox 3.6 32-bit and IE 9 built into WINE with Java 1.6 32-bit. Safari, Firefox and Chrome all fail under OS X when running Java 1.8 (as expected).

## My Setup

---

#### Server

PowerEdge 2850 with DRAC 4/I running Ubuntu 14.04 with OpenMange installed.

#### Client

Firefox 3.6 32-bit with Java 1.6.0_45 32-bit in WINE on Early 2009 iMac running OS X 10.11

Comment: Such problems are hard to diagnose without more insight. The best way to find out what exactly is going on is to dump the traffic using a tool like wireshark.

Comment: @KonradGajewski Thanks! I'll look into it. What information (including/within packets sent between my client and the server) should I be adding here? I'm not very familiar with networking, and I've personally never used Wireshark: will it be fine for analyzing packets sent with SSL? How can I ensure I also don't leak personal/sensitive data?

Comment: Publish the entire dump somewhere to download. You will potentially leak passwords, but since it is not working... anyway... dump the traffic and change the password.

Comment: @KonradGajewski Afraid that for me that's not a safe approach, sorry. Thanks for the help though.